# Cannot read private member #serverSocket from an object whose class did not declare it

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code in my browser I get the following error. The error happens inside the #monitorConnection() method.

> Cannot read private member #serverSocket from an object whose class
> did not declare it

```
class ControlPanel {
    #serverSocket;
    constructor() {
        this.#connectToWebSocketServer();
        this.#monitorConnection();
        console.log("ControlPanel::new");
    }
    #connectToWebSocketServer() {
        this.#serverSocket = new WebSocket(window.location.toString().startsWith('https')
          ? window.location.toString().replace("https", "wss")
          : window.location.toString().replace("http", "wss")
        );
        this.#serverSocket.onclose = this.#onWebSocketClose;
        this.#serverSocket.onerror = this.#onWebSocketError;
        this.#serverSocket.onmessage = this.#onWebSocketMessage;
        this.#serverSocket.onopen = this.#onWebSocketOpen;
        console.log("ControlPanel::#connectToWebSocketServer");
    }
    #monitorConnection() {
        setInterval(function() { if(this.#serverSocket.readyState != 1) this.#connectToWebSocketServer() }, 1500);
    }
    #onWebSocketClose(event) {
        console.debug("ControlPanel::#onWebSocketClose ", event);
    }
    #onWebSocketError(event) {
        console.debug("ControlPanel::#onWebSocketError ", event);
    }
    #onWebSocketMessage(event) {
        console.log("ControlPanel::#onWebSocketMessage ", event);
    }
    #onWebSocketOpen(event) {
        console.debug("ControlPanel::#onWebSocketOpen ", event);
    }
}
const controlPanel = new slim.generator.ControlPanel();
```

When I update the following method it gets the same error when the websocket first connects.

```
    #onWebSocketOpen(event) {
        console.debug("ControlPanel::#onWebSocketOpen ", event);
        this.#serverSocket.send();
    }
```

Comment: Try defining function out of `function() {
if(this.#serverSocket.readyState != 1) this.#connectToWebSocketServer() 
}` and passing the name of that function into your setInterval (my wild guess)

Comment: You are correct. My problem is one of not paying close enough attention to scope. Thanks.

Comment: You could pass the reference from the socket like this: `setInterval(function(socket, instance) { /* do something with socket */ }, 1500, this.#serversocket, this);`

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this` in

```
setInterval(function() {
   if(this.#serverSocket.readyState != 1) this.#connectToWebSocketServer() }
, 1500);
```

is `undefined` given code within class declarations runs in strict mode.

Using an arrow function expression, which captures the lexical `this` value when evaluated, is the common solution:

```
setInterval(() => { if(this.#serverSocket.readyState != 1) this.#connectToWebSocketServer() }\
, 1500);
```

---

See Also:  "No this substitution" under ["Securing" JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#securing_javascript) for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Rojo,answered this for me.

The problem is one of scope. The following added method works.

```
#start() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(() => { if(self.#serverSocket.readyState > 1) self.#connectToWebSocketServer() }, 1500);
}
```